# How to extract Text regions in images using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I am writing a `matlab` program that will detect text in a natural scene images. I am taking help of [this video lecture and paper](http://videolectures.net/cvpr2010_epshtein_dtns). I understood first few steps and did edge detection (I am adding images below). Now I want to extract(separate out) only text from final image. How do I do that?

My code:

```
i = imread('f:\new.jpg');
i1 = rgb2gray(i);
imshow(i1);

i2 = edge(i1,'canny',0.3);
imshow(i2);

se = strel('square',2);
i3 = imdilate(i2,se);
imshow(i3);

i4 = imfill(i3,'holes');
imshow(i4);

[Ilabel num] = bwlabel(i4);
disp(num);
Iprops = regionprops(Ilabel);
Ibox = [Iprops.BoundingBox];
Ibox = reshape(Ibox,[4 92]);
imshow(i);

hold on;
for cnt = 1:92
    rectangle('position',Ibox(:,cnt),'edgecolor','r');
end
```

Final image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To crop out part of the image is to take sub-matrix from matrix knowing it's bounding indexes. For example if sub-matrix is stretching from `y1` row to `y2` row and from `x1` column to `x2` column (all bounds inclusive) you would get sub-matrix with:

```
submat = mainmat(y1:y2,x1:x2);
```

Before extracting sub-matrices you have to get bounding coordinates for every letter. If you have `y` and `x` coordinates for one letter; be it all coordinates of the region of the image, or just coordinates of the edge of an region, you can get bounding coordinates with:

```
% x-coordinates of the region are in the vector x
x1 = min( x(:) );
x2 = max( x(:) );
% y-coordinates of the region are in the vector y
y1 = min( y(:) );
y2 = max( y(:) );
```

After doing above procedure for all of the letters you could then separate letters one-by-one, but if you would like to separate out connected regions of letters you would have to check for overlapping of letter's bounding rectangles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how would I crop out text regions only as there are bounding boxes around many unnecessary things?could you provide some help on this?

Comment: @Heisenberg Do I need to be more specific with: 1. the procedure of finding out bounding coordinates in your particular case? 2. obtaining connected regions of letters? I can't do it at the moment, but will maybe have time later...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now at least have some clue about what to do next :)